# Searching in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

How can I search for specific text in Visual Studio but ignore it in certain cases?  Basically, I'm searching for the project name anywhere in the project code but I don't want every single page, being that the namespace fits my search, I'm getting a hit on every page.

so for example, I need to find all occurances of "foobar.com" while ignoring it if it's "admin.foobar.com.admin".  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried a regex search, or use "Whole word only" in the search options?

Comment: using "whole word only" still finds "foobar.com" in "admin.foobar.com.admin".  I'm terrible with regex's

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
~(admin\.)foobar\.com~(\.admin)
```

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

hope this helps,

Answer (score -1):

Use the Regular Expression search option.

1. Type CTRL-Shift-F (for Find in Files dialog)
2. In the "Find What" field, enter "[^admin.]foobar.com"
3. In the "Look In" dropdown, select Entire Solution (or limit to whatever you want to)
4. Expand the "Find Options" and select "Regular Expressions" in the "Use:" dropdown
5. Click "Find All"

NOTE: This will only eliminate instances where "admin." precedes "foobar.com".

Comment: No, it doesn't do what you think it does.  Your search expression will find every occurrence of `foobar.com` that is **not** preceded by 'a' 'd' 'm' 'i' 'n' or '.' character, i.e., it will **skip** `afoobar.com`, `dfoobar.com` `mfoobar.com`, `ifoobar.com`, `nfoobar.com` and `.foobar.com` but will find every other foobar.com